# How to determine position of spiral overlay with opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, collision-detection, object-detection

This started as a joke but now I'm wondering how to do this in opencv (python):

1. Given any image with width and height >= 500px (any aspect ratio).
2. Overlay a fibonacci rectangle on the image with the **best fit**.

[image]

*Note*: The following transformations are permitted on the fibonacci rectangle overlay: **scale**, **rotate**, **horizontal flip**, **vertical flip**.  The source image can also be **cropped** or **resized** to accommodate the best fit.

Since **best fit** is subjective, here are some of my general criteria in priority order:

1. If there is a prominent circle or circular object in the image, the spiral should trace the edge of this object as much as possible.
2. If there is a prominent arc or arc-like object in the image, the spiral should trace the edge of this object as much as possible.
3. If there are no prominent circular or arc-like objects in the image, the spiral should terminate at an 'interesting' area of the image.

For example:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

These 4 are the best out of thousands of attempts generated by my very naive method, which just finds the quadrant of the image with the highest density of information. When it works, it's pretty much just pure luck. I'd like to go from pure luck to something *slightly* better.

Thanks for your time.